# How to render a modal on top of a screen

Tags: react-native, modal-dialog, wix-react-native-navigation

I am implementing firebase cloud messaging in my react native app. I have a regular class (not a react component) with static methods and variables that is instantiated when app fires. This class have three static methods/listeners (foreground, background and launch app) to manage push notifications from firebase.

I am trying to handle actions when in foreground. 
How do I render a modal on top of a screen (not switching screens but run an overlay card in the center with two buttons), when user receives a push message from firebase, regardless of which screen he is on?

Tried solution provided on this article at hackernoon, wrapping modal component inside the AppContainer did not do anything. https://hackernoon.com/managing-react-modals-with-singleton-component-design-5efdd317295b

I have also tried the idea on this tutorial with modal component, but have not succeed in any cases.
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigating-without-navigation-prop.html

Firebase cloud messaging class:

```
 export default class FCM {
static appClosedListener = async () => {
    const firebaseContent = await firebase.notifications().getInitialNotification();

    if (firebaseContent) {
      console.log(firebaseContent);
      const serverParcel = JSON.parse(firebaseContent._data.payload).an;
      const notificationState = "closedapp";
      FCM.pushNotificationHandler(serverParcel, notificationState);
    }
  };

  static backgroundListener = () => {
    FCM.background = firebase.notifications().onNotificationOpened(firebaseContent => {
      const serverParcel = JSON.parse(firebaseContent._data.payload).an;
      const notificationState = "background";
      FCM.pushNotificationHandler(serverParcel, notificationState);
    });
  };

  static foregroundListener = () => {
    FCM.foreground = firebase.notifications().onNotification(firebaseContent => {
      const serverParcel = JSON.parse(firebaseContent._data.payload).an;
      const notificationState = "foreground";
      FCM.pushNotificationHandler(serverParcel, notificationState);
    });
  };

  static pushNotificationHandler = (serverParcel, notificationState) => {
    const typeOfAction = serverParcel.typeEnum;
    switch(typeOfAction){
      case "message":
        break;

      case "webnews":
        const url = serverParcel.link;
        NavigationService.navigate("FCMModal", {}); //Here is where I want the modal to popup.
        //NavigationService.navigate("InAppBrowser", {url});
        break;
    }
  }
```

App.js

```
const ModalStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    FCMModal: FCMModal
  },
  {
    mode: 'modal',
    transparentCard: true,
    cardStyle: {
      // makes transparentCard work for android
      opacity: 1.0
    }
  }
)

    let rootStack = createStackNavigator(
      {
        main: {
          screen: BottomTabNavigator //There are four navigatorstacks with multiple screens beneath here
        },
        InAppBrowser: {
          screen: InAppBrowserStack,
          defaultNavigationOptions: {
            tabBarVisible: true
          }
        },
        FCMModal: {
          screen: ModalStack
        }
      },
      {
        initialRouteName: "main",
        headerMode: "none"
      }
    );

    const AppContainer = createAppContainer(rootStack);
    export default class App extends Component {
      render() {
        return (
          <AppContainer 
            ref={navigatorRef => {
              NavigationService.setTopLevelNavigator(navigatorRef);
            }}
          />     
        );
      }
    }
```

Modal class

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Modal, Text, TouchableHighlight, View } from 'react-native';

export default class FCMModal extends Component {
  state = {
    modalVisible: true,
  };

  setModalVisible(visible) {
    this.setState({modalVisible: visible});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{width: 600, height: 400, borderWidth: 2, borderColor: 'red', opacity: 0.5}}>
        <Modal
          animationType="slide"
          transparent={true}
          visible={this.state.modalVisible}
          onRequestClose={() => {console.log("CLOSING MODAL!")}}>
          <View style={{marginTop: 22}}>
            <View>
              <Text>Hello World!</Text>

              <TouchableHighlight
                onPress={() => {
                  this.setModalVisible(false);
                }}>
                <Text>Hide Modal</Text>
              </TouchableHighlight>
            </View>
          </View>
        </Modal>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```